# Failure to mount local volume when the volume is a child directory of pwd

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to start a service with `docker-compose up` where the volume is referencing `${PWD}/data`. The `data/` directory does not exist before `docker-compose up` is run.

This causes an exception. I thought the `docker-compose up` call would create `{PWD}/data` rather than giving this exception.

```
test-docker-compose_tor_1 is up-to-date
Creating test-docker-compose_walletserver_1 ... error

ERROR: for test-docker-compose_walletserver_1  Cannot create container for service walletserver: failed to mount local volume: mount /tmp/test-docker-compose/data:/var/lib/docker/volumes/bitcoin-s/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

ERROR: for walletserver  Cannot create container for service walletserver: failed to mount local volume: mount /tmp/test-docker-compose/data:/var/lib/docker/volumes/bitcoin-s/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

This is how i have the `docker-compose.yml` defined. How do i get my `docker-compose.yml` to create `${PWD}/data` if the directory does not exist?

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  walletserver:
    image: bitcoinscala/bitcoin-s-server:latest
    entrypoint: ["/opt/docker/bin/bitcoin-s-server", "--datadir", "/bitcoin-s", "--conf", "/opt/docker/docker-application.conf"]
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - datadir:/bitcoin-s 
volumes: 
  datadir:
    name: "bitcoin-s"
    driver: local
    external: false
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none 
      device: ${PWD}/data # note if i change this to ${PWD}, this works
```

Here are my versions

```
 docker --version                                                                                                    
Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701
```

```
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the volume as a bind mount in the service configuration, like this, it will work:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  walletserver:
    image: bitcoinscala/bitcoin-s-server:latest
    entrypoint: ["/opt/docker/bin/bitcoin-s-server", "--datadir", "/bitcoin-s", "--conf", "/opt/docker/docker-application.conf"]
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./data:/bitcoin-s
```

It looks like using the extended volume syntax has different behavior (arguably, the extended volume syntax has the *correct* behavior: automatically creating the directory may seem convenient, but it hides typos and can lead to unexpected behavior when you misspell a file and transform your config file into a directory).

Comment: I run into file permissions issues on the host machine with being able to make the container run as the uid of the user on the host machine. 

For some reason, it seems that root ends up owning my directories on the host if I do not run the container as  `"$(id -u):$(id -g)"`. 

When i use the extended volume syntax, permissions seem to be maintained correctly when passing the hosts' uid. If I use the shortened syntax as you suggest, the volume `./data/` folder is owned by root rather than the hosts `uid`

Answer (score -1):

There are two different alternatives for mounting your directories from host into the container. One is using -v (or --volume) and the other one is --mount. The difference between these two is exactly what you asked for. By using -v docker would create the given directory in the location if it does not already exist and the other one returns an error.

Now for using this in docker-compose you can easily use the `type` tag for selecting the -v instead of --mount.

You can also specify the user id of the container using `user: "${UID}:${GID}"` or `user: root` on your docker-compose.yml

You would probably need something like this:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  walletserver:
    image: bitcoinscala/bitcoin-s-server:latest
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    entrypoint: ["/opt/docker/bin/bitcoin-s-server", "--datadir", "/bitcoin-s", "--conf", "/opt/docker/docker-application.conf"]
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: "datadir"
        target: "/bitcoin-s"
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question, which is about creating the volume in `${PWD}/data`, which doesn't seem to be possible AFAICT.

Comment: Using volumes with type bind would create the directory if it does not exist already and you asked how to make docker compose to make the directory. I am not following what else the question might need.